# Set database from SINGLE USER mode to MULTI USER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with setting a database that was restored in `SINGLE_USER` mode to `MULTI_USER`. Every time I run

```
ALTER DATABASE BARDABARD
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

I get this error:

> Changes to the state or options of database 'BARDABARD' cannot be made at this time.
>
> The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.

It needs to be in non-`SINGLE_USER` mode to set it to another mode, but I can’t set the database in any another mode while it is `SINGLE_USER` mode.

Comment: In `single user mode` SQL server acepts only one connection. So close all the windows in the SSMS or any service, application, website using your database. Important thing to know is that even if you expand a node in the SSMS Object Explorer or Object Explorer Details window it will be treated as a connection.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The “user is currently connected to it” might be SQL Server Management Studio window itself. Try selecting the master database and running the `ALTER` query again.

Comment: Adding to this: It appears that a query window may be attached to the database even though some *other* database (such as `master`) is selected in the *Available Databases* toolbar drop-down when the query window is active. If it keeps giving you headaches, close **all** other query windows, and select some innocent system database like `master` or `tempdb` in the drop-down in the one window you have left.

Comment: Try to disconnect the DB and connect again in microsoft SQL server management studio. Then run the command again.

Comment: The first comment is very helpful and could be added to the answer, actually. I couldn't run the query before I closed all other queries.

Comment: I had to take the database offline (ContextMenu -> Tasks -> Take Offline), perform the action from this answer, and then bring the database back online to make it work.

Answer (score 100):

That error message generally means there are other processes connected to the DB.  Try running this to see which are connected:

```
exec sp_who
```

That will return you the process and then you should be able to run:

```
kill [XXX]
```

Where [xxx] is the `spid` of the process you're trying to kill.

Then you can run your above statement.

Comment: kill [xxx] gets rid of the process, but when I try to run my command, it comes back!

Comment: In my case, we had a service that had stolen the single user access and it would reconnect very quickly. I had to run `kill <spid>` with a `go` immediately followed by the `set multi_user` statement. I suspect that a `use [affected_db]` immediately afterwards would be enough to steal the single user connection, too.

Answer (score 90):

You can add the option to rollback your change immediately.

```
ALTER DATABASE BARDABARD
SET MULTI_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Comment: What does `ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` exactly do?

Comment: @dakab Forces all pending transactions to rollback immediately as of the start of the `ALTER DATABASE` statement's transaction, as opposed to `WITH ROLLBACK X SECONDS` which waits for transactions to finish before forcing them to rollback or to wait indefinitely until there are no pending transactions (which I believe is the default but can't seem to find in the doc at the moment).  It's the equivalent of "stop everything you're doing right now and do this."

Answer (score 42):

SQL Server 2012:

right-click on the `DB > Properties > Options > [Scroll down] State > RestrictAccess > select Multi_user` and click OK.

Voila!

Comment: Not really, this is what I received when tried your solution :/ "Database 'XXX' is already open and can only have one user at a time. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 924)"

Comment: Additionally confirmed in SQL 2008R2.

Comment: Best answer, working even in cases where you haven't permission to use KILL statement

Comment: Excellent answer. Since Mgt Studio tree already holds the only available session, why not use it to change the db property.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue and it fixed by the following steps - reference: http://giladka8.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/database-is-in-single-user-mode-and.html

```
use master
GO

select 
    d.name, 
    d.dbid, 
    spid, 
    login_time, 
    nt_domain, 
    nt_username, 
    loginame
from sysprocesses p 
    inner join sysdatabases d 
        on p.dbid = d.dbid
where d.name = 'dbname'
GO

kill 56 --=> kill the number in spid field
GO

exec sp_dboption 'dbname', 'single user', 'FALSE'
GO
```

Answer (score 20):

I have just fixed using following steps, It may help you.

**Step: 1**

[image: right click on single user database]

---

**Step: 2**

[image: take offline]

---

**Step: 3**

[image: Drop connection and take offline]

---

**Step: 4**

[image: Take online]

---

**Step: 5**

Then run following query.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDBName
SET MULTI_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Enjoy...!

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: First running the SQL command, and then bringing the database back online also worked for me. Might be useful to know in scenarios where another service is trying to connect to the database.

Answer (score 17):

This worked fine for me.

Step 1. Right click on database engine, click on activity monitor and see  which process is having connection. Kill that particular user and execute the query Immediately.

Step 2.

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseNameHere] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
```

and refresh the database.

Answer (score 10):

I actually had an issue where my db was pretty much locked by the processes and a race condition with them, by the time I got one command executed refreshed and they had it locked again... I had to run the following commands back to back in SSMS and got me offline and from there I did my restore and came back online just fine, the two queries where:

First ran:

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';'
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE dbid = db_id('<yourDbName>')

EXEC(@kill);
```

Then immediately after (in second query window):

```
USE master ALTER DATABASE <yourDbName> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Did what I needed and then brought it back online. Thanks to all who wrote these pieces out for me to combine and solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

It may be best to log onto the server directly instead of using SQL Management Studio

Ensure that the account you login as is dbowner for the database you want to set to MULTI_USER. Login as sa (using SQL server authentication) if you can

**If your database is used by IIS, stop the website and the app pool that use it** - this may be the process that's connected and blocking you from setting to MULTI_USER

```
USE MASTER
GO

-- see if any process are using *your* database specifically

SELECT * from master.sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid > 50 -- process spids < 50 are reserved by SQL - we're not interested in these
AND dbid=DB_ID ('YourDbNameHere')

-- if so, kill the process:

KILL n -- where 'n' is the 'spid' of the connected process as identified using query above

-- setting database to read only isn't generally necessary, but may help:

ALTER DATABASE YourDbNameHere
SET READ_ONLY;
GO

-- should work now:

ALTER DATABASE Appswiz SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Refer here if you still have trouble:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/04/07/help-i-m-stuck-in-single-user-mode-and-can-t-get-out/

**AS A LAST ALTERNATIVE** - If you've tried everything above and you're getting desperate you could try stopping the SQL server instance and start it again

Answer (score 4):

You couldn't do that becouse database in single mode. Above all right but you should know that: when you opened the sql management studio it doesn't know any user on the database but when you click the database it consider you the single user and your command not working.
Just do that: Close management studio and re open it. new query window without selecting any database write the command script.

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tuncayoto] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
```

make f5 wolla everything ok !

Comment: Of all the answers, this was the only one that worked for me. Here's your upvote!

Answer (score 2):

The code below has worked for me when I didn't know the specific SPID that was used to change into `singleuser` mode.

```
use master
GO

select 
    d.name, 
    d.dbid, 
    spid, 
    login_time, 
    nt_domain, 
    nt_username, 
    loginame
from sysprocesses p 
    inner join sysdatabases d 
        on p.dbid = d.dbid
where d.name = 'dbname'
GO

kill 52 -- kill the number in spid field
GO

exec sp_dboption 'dbname', 'single user', 'FALSE'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Tried everything didn't work
2. Login to that server remotely as we gonna kill all connections
3. run the below code more than once till it returns completed and no "killing process" test anymore
4. reactivate it again using the code below the below code

> use master GO declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int
>
> select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid =
>   db_id('DB_NAME')  and spid != @@spid
>
> while (@spid is not null) begin
>       print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
>       set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
>       exec (@sql)
>
> ```
> select 
>     @spid = min(spid)  
> from 
>     master..sysprocesses  
> where 
>     dbid = db_id('DB_NAME') 
>     and spid != @@spid end
> ```

then to bring it back alive

> ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME SET MULTI_USER; GO

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me

1. Take a backup
2. Create new database and restore the backup to it
3. Then Properties > Options > [Scroll down] State > RestrictAccess > select Multi_user and click OK
4. Delete the old database

Hope this work for all
Thank you
Ramesh Kumar

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work, find the loginname of the spid and disable it in Security - Logins

Answer (score 1):

What I do:

First I kill all database process, to certificate that database isn't in use.
After I alter the user mode.

Sometimes a process is quickly grabed again from an aplication, and I need run this process one more time...

**Replace the expression DATABASE_NAME below, to use your database name.**

**--Kill process**

```
USE Master 
GO

declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int

select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid = db_id('DATABASE_NAME')  and spid != @@spid    

while (@spid is not null) 
begin
    print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
    set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
    exec (@sql)

    select 
        @spid = min(spid)  
    from 
        master..sysprocesses  
    where 
        spid > 50 AND dbid = db_id('DATABASE_NAME') 
        and spid != @@spid 
end 

print 'Killing Process completed...' 
GO

**--Alter user mode** 

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME SET MULTI_USER; 

GO 

print 'Alter Database Process completed...'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem easily

1. Right click on database name rename it
2. After changing, right click on database name --> properties --> options --> go to bottom of scrolling RestrictAccess (SINGLE_USER to MULTI_USER)
3. Now again you can rename database as your old name.

Answer (score 0):

**just go to database properties** 
and change SINGLE USER mode to MULTI USER

[image]

NOTE:
if its not work for you then take Db backup and restore again and do above method again

*
Single=SINGLE_USER

Multiple=MULTI_USER

Restricted=RESTRICTED_USER

Comment: How is this any different from the query OP is using?

Comment: yes both will work same ,this is same like instead of using CREATE Table query we used sql server GUI Table Designer to make Table,BTS both will work same ,one is query method and other is GUI method. use what ever you like.

Comment: OP is clearly stating that hes query results in an error. As you are saying this is the exact same thing as using the query you are not giving an answer at all, you are just cluttering up and adding to the many wrong answers here

Answer (score 0):

On more than 3 occasions working with SQL Server 2014, I have had a database convert to Single User mode without me changing anything. It must have occurred during database creation somehow. All of the methods above never worked as I always received an error that the database was in single user mode and could not be connected to.

The only thing I got to work was restarting the SQL Server Windows Service. That allowed me to connect to the database and make the necessary changes or to delete the database and start over.

Answer (score 0):

After going in to the Single-User mode, a client can establish only ONE connection with the SQL Server, remember that "Object Explorer" takes up a (separate) connection, so if you are trying run a Multi-User statement in a query window, you will get error that in Single-User mode you can't establish another connection.

For me this wasn't the issue though, in my case, there were few automated processes that were persistently (in every few seconds) establishing connections, so as soon as I took the DB into Single-User mode and disconnected myself, one of the processes established/occupied the connection (before I could start my Restore operation). As soon as I'd kill those connections - they'd reconnect and when I ran the Restore command, I would get the error that connection is already occupied.

To resolve this I had to write the `kill` statements, change of `User-Mode` statements and `Restore` operations all in one query window and when I ran them all in one go, voila!!! it worked.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with a local DB.

I was able to solve this problem by stopping SQL server, and then starting SQL server, and then using the SSMS UI to change the DB properties to Multi_User.

The DB went into "Single User" Mode when i was attempting to restore a backup. I hadn't created a backup of the target database before attempting to restore (SQL 2017). this will get you every time.

Stop SQL Server, Start SQL Server, then run the above Scripts or use the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for the solution for a while and finally came up with the below solution,

SSMS in general uses several connections to the database behind the scenes.

**You will need to kill these connections before changing the access mode.**(I have done it with **EXEC(@kill);** in the code template below.)

Then,

Run the following SQL to **set the database in MULTI_USER mode.**

```
USE master
GO
DECLARE @kill varchar(max) = '';
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'KILL ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), spid) + '; '
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE spid > 50 AND dbid = DB_ID('<Your_DB_Name>')
EXEC(@kill);

GO
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

To switch back to Single User mode, you can use:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET SINGLE_USER
```

This should work. Happy coding!!

Thanks!!