# I closed SQL Connection and Can't Open it back up

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used this query to close all the connections to SQL Server (Windows Authentication)

```
alter database YourDb set single_user with rollback immediate
```

And now i get this error on my web app

> Cannot open database "DataCleanup" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'BIVAR\DEV_WEB_VM$'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "DataCleanup" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'BIVAR\DEV_WEB_VM$'.

Source Error:

```
Line 91:                 
Line 92:                 {
Line 93:                     sqlCon2.Open();
Line 94:                     {
Line 95:                         //PM3-PM5-PR
```

I'm not sure how to open the connection for everyone again?

Comment: And where you close the connection...

Comment: What does your DBA say?

Comment: This post may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652923/set-database-from-single-user-mode-to-multi-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly connect to *a different* database first.  I'd suggest [master] or [tempdb].  Then you can open it back up with:

```
alter database YourDb set multi_user;
```

The problem that you are having right now, is probably that you are not explicitly specifying a databse so it is going to your default, which is likely [YourDb].  If there's already a coonection to that DB (even one from you), then you won't be able to make the connection.