# Cannot get access to SQL Server database after first access

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I get the following error message when I attempt to connect to my database.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

This is the 3rd time that I removed and reinstalled it. On the first successful login, it is fine. Second time, I make changes to the database and get errors about not being able to find the database. I close the program and upon reopening get this error message.

It is confusing but this is SQL Server Express even though it says SQL Server Management Studio 17 upon opening.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: How do you connect to the database? In your own application? If so: could you share some code? And what does your connection string look like (please don't post sensitive information like username / password if its included in the connection string)

Comment: Server Type: Database Engine
XX327###\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: Windows authentication
Username: Dept/Name  (This is grayed out)

This box pops up when I click on the icon for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: Do you connect from the PC where you installed SQLExpress or form a remote PC?

Comment: The PC where I installed it.

Comment: Did you already have a look in the Windows Services if the sqlepxress Service is still running on that pc? Another thing you can try is to use .\sqlexpress instead of XX327###\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I will check out those possibilities.

Comment: What changes are you making?

Comment: I create a database and then create a table with two columns. In this last instance, I renamed the table and the backup.

Comment: Not sure why it was doing the things described but it was a user permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure database or instance is not in single-user mode.

To change it on instance-level you have to modify the launch parameters of your instance into `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

To change it on database-level you have to modify the SINGLE USER option :
[Set database from SINGLE USER mode to MULTI USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652923/set-database-from-single-user-mode-to-multi-user)

Comment: OK, I will look into this. It may be a few days before I can get back to this.