# How to permanently set database to SINGLE_USER Mode?

Tags: sql-server

I implemented log shipping using dbatools command and was testing it out today. What ive noticed is when i query the restored/standby database, like a select on a table, the restore of transaction log fails until i disconnect from the instance.

```
Message
2021-09-24 23:00:23.60  *** Error: Could not apply log backup file '\\devops\c$\Users\devops_user\Documents\DBLogShipping\Backups\LogShippingFiles\test12345\test12345_20210924225000.trn' to secondary database 'test12345'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2021-09-24 23:00:23.60  *** Error: Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider) ***
```

[image: standby/read]

I found out that by setting the database to SINGLE_USER mode:

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE test12345
SET SINGLE_USER
--This rolls back all uncommitted transactions in the db.
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

[image: single user]

the restore job will actually work fine whilst querying the database, so no need to disconnect from the server. I mean that is great! However, when i disconnected and reconnected later to the instance, I saw the SINGLE_USER mode disappeared...it looks like it reverted back to the default multi_user mode?

Is there a way to permanently have the database set in SINGLE USER mode?

Comment: I just executed the query again, and i received the following messages: `Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.` and now even if i disconnect and reconnect, i see SINGLE user mode is applied. However, now I am unable to expand the database nor execute the restore job successfully...interesting!

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver15#db_user_access_option-): "The database remains in SINGLE_USER mode even if the user that set the option signs out. At that point, a different user, but only one, can connect to the database." Have you actually checked using `select name, user_access from sys.databases`? Note that Object Explorer in SSMS uses a separate connection, so you need to disconnect it

Comment: @Charlieface I see. I reverted the database back to `MULTI_USER` mode by following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58062858/8397835 and now the restores are working successfully again.